# Slope estimator for the regression line through the origin

Tags: regression, least-squares, regression-coefficients

For a regression line through the origin with the equation:

$$ \tilde{y}=\tilde{\beta_1}x $$

How did we use OLS to get the below equation? I know it is by minimising the SSR but I can't seem to work it out by plugging in the values into the formula for SSR.

$$ \sum (y_i -\tilde{\beta_1}x_i)^2 $$

And furthermore, how do we use calculus to get the first order condition for equation directly above?

First order condition:

$$ \sum x_i(y_i-\tilde{\beta_1}x_i) = 0 $$

Is it a partial derivative? If so, where did the exponent (2) go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the derivative. For example, our loss function is the sum of squared residuals, or 
$$
S(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \beta x_i)^2.
$$
We want to minimize this, so we take the first derivative:
$$
\frac{dS}{d\beta} = -2 \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \beta x_i) x_i.
$$

We set it equal to zero to find the minimum, so 
$$
-2 \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \hat{\beta} x_i) x_i = 0 \\
\hat{\beta} =\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n y_i x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}.
$$

The exponent gets pulled down (it's the power rule in calculus).

Comment: Why is our loss function the sum of squared residuals? Is it because $ \hat{u}=\tilde{y}-\tilde{beta_1}x $?

Comment: For OLS (ordinary *least squares*), the loss function is the sum of squared errors, as it yields estimators with good properties. You could certainly use a different loss function on a regression problem, but then it wouldn't be OLS.